# How to add a string resource to strings.xml in a cordova project

Tags: cordova, gradle

When issuing `cordova build android`, a `build.gradle` file is auto generated.
I'd like this script to insert a variable to the `strings.xml` file. I can do this by adding a `resValue` line to `build.gradle` but I don't want to change that auto-generated file.
Anyway to achieve that?

Answer (score 4):

You can add the string in plugin.xml.

```
    <config-file target="res/values/strings.xml" parent="/*">
        <string name="pick_any_option">Pick any option...</string>
    </config-file>
```